# Sum of products of edges of all paths in DAG

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph

I have a directed acyclic graph with weighted edges. My goal is to find the sum of products of edges in all paths between "the first" and "the last" levels. For example, in this case this would be 2*3 + 2*1 + 4*2 + 4*4 + 3*3 + 3*1 + 2*2 + 2*4 = 56. In the real graph, I have 20-30 levels. Is there any efficient way to do this?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dynamic programming - start from the last level and go backwards. For each node v compute the sum S[v] for the paths from this node to the last level.

For the last level this S[v] = 0 for all v. 
If you have the S[v] for all nodes in level i+1 then you compute for all nodes in level i:  S[u] = sum{v, s.t. (u,v) is an edge} weight(u,v) * S[v].

Comment: to do the DP solution you have to do a `topological sort` on the graph to determine the levels of your graph. better just run a `DFS` on the graph and  compute the productSum in realTime.

Comment: It's actually worked perfecetly for my purposes, since all my graphs have absolutely similar structure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `DFS` to solve this :

```
    Node s; // starting node
    Integer result = 0
    Function sumProduct(Node currentNode){
            mark currentNode as visited
            for each connected node to currentNode which is not visited do

                 result += edgeCost(currentNode to neighbor) + sumProduct(Neighbor);
            end for

                 return result
    }

// call function with the starting node: 

sumProduct(s);
```